# How to get only specific condition records

Tags: sql

How to get only specific condition records-

Input table-

```
Name    SyS_Access
M   X
M   Y
M   Z
P   S
P   Z
W   Z
R   X
E   Z
```

Output table-
get the name those have only access of "Z" sys_access.

result-

```
Name    SyS_Access
W   Z
E   Z
```

Comment: which dbms are you using? also what have you tried

Comment: Please explain more

Comment: sql server 2008

Comment: need a records those have only and only "z" sys_access.if i put sys_access='Z' then getting M,P,W and E but i need only W and E.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with `group by`:

```
select name, max(sys_access)
from t
group by name
having min(sys_access) = max(sys_access) and max(sys_access) = 'Z';
```

Comment: ,it was only example we can take based on max function. eg -  Name  SyS_Access
M app1
M app2
M app3
M app4
M app5
P app4
P app5
W app3
R app5
E app3
L app5
 
 now i want in result those have only app3 access.

Comment: @Murari . . . If you have a different question, then you should ask as a *different* question.  This answers the one you have asked.